# samba net command on Debian Wheezy

Tags: raspbian, packages, samba

Which package for Debian Wheezy holds the 'net' command?
I am running Raspbian 7 (Debian Wheezy) with samba-common and samba packages installed. But can not locate net.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer is correct as written previously:

Install samba-common-bin with

```
apt-get install samba-common-bin
```

In the case of Raspbian,  peterretief was incorrect. I have just verified it. I had installed samba-common and was unable to use net. after installing samba-common-bin, it works.  peterretief  also said that there were other ways to accomplish the same thing. As a Raspbian newbie, I would love to know what those are. Some references to articles or man pages would have been quite helpful.

Comment: I think you meant "peterretief was **correct**" since he was presumably asking why the answer you have also said is correct was downvoted.  *"As a Raspbian newbie, I would love to know what those are..."* -> Raspbian == [Debian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian), questions about which mostly (including any and all those involving samba) belong on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3):

Install `samba-common-bin` with `apt-get install samba-common-bin`.

Comment: Why is this answer wrong? net is part of samba common - I don't use it because there are so many tools in Linux that do the same thing